# How can I send mail with my company domain through gmail smtp server

Tags: c#, email, gmail, google-workspace

I found a lot of questions and solutions to mail with gmail but I can't get the code to work with my company's domain. When I use my own gmail it works like a charm.

I have activated 2FA and generated a password for both account's. When I mail using my own gmail account it works. But when I try to mail using my company's account which is using the G Suite it does not work. I receive this exception:

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at'`

Here is my code:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
      UseDefaultCredentials = false,
      Credentials = new NetworkCredential("********@mydomain.nl", "************"),
      EnableSsl = true
};
client.Send("********@mydomain.nl", "*******@live.nl", "test", "testbody");
Console.WriteLine("Sent");
Console.ReadLine();
```

I have checked all the settings 10 times over. How can I get this to work?

Comment: needs the credentials to be correct, otherwise it'll be considered relayed spam - definite no-no, not poassible.  Have you considered setting the Reply-To: header to an email in your companies domain?

Comment: thinking further, why can you not use the companies smtp?  (if they have a domain the hosting should provide smtp if not self hosted) using gmail for company email would be pretty unprofessional.

Comment: @Rob: He means G Suite, which is for the company's domain.

Comment: The company uses the G Suite as @SLaks mentions, I can not change this. Also I can not change the administrator settings.